# Get text from <a> tags in text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm getting html content from API.

Sample message could look like below

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="https://example.com">example.com</a>
Pellentesque porta ligula et justo condimentum, nec tincidunt libero tempor.
Pellentesque nunc justo, tincidunt sit amet suscipit sit amet, auctor <a href="https://google.com">google.com</a>
```

I need my message to look line below, plain text with

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet example.com
Pellentesque porta ligula et justo condimentum, nec tincidunt libero tempor.
Pellentesque nunc justo, tincidunt sit amet suscipit sit amet, auctor google.com
```

I've tried to use regex with groups, js code below

```js
const r = /^<a href.*>(.*?)<\/a>$/gm

let link = `<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a> test <a href="test.com">test.com</a>`

let result

while((result = r.exec(link)) !== null) {
  const match = result[1];
  link = link.replace(r, match)
}

console.log(link)
```

I also tried simple code like below

```js
const r = /^<a href.*>(.*?)<\/a>$/gm

let link = `<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a> test <a href="test.com">test.com</a>`

link = link.replaceAll(r, "$1")

console.log(link)
```

Unfortunately, in both cases after running my code console.log prints "test.com", not whole message.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: If you do request on API with jQuery you can set dataType as text instead of html. It should be stripped for you directly.

Comment: I'm using Angular. I need html content to display message, but I need plain content to edit message (backend is parsing links to <a> tags)

Comment: if you need better regex try this <a href[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>

Comment: Sounds like a simple replacement, see [this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##ZVBBTsMwELznFateWlCIrwjS9AMcuFNQt86SurK9xl5X/D5shaBF3HZHM6OZOeIJi80uyd3pfp49CRTJsIbdE2cK4FKpAUb2nKE4AQzK6BEOmd7Xi4NIKg/G0CeG5KmzHBbD1dMbHJpn8p6iUPmoBImzIHg3VY@gVsdahMFyHF1QUg0tRLIgLlo31ihK3VNmEAoq7f6axRrtt0N7pfiNWWqxLrkL0gJWK9rkX4GJefrJf7nP8XePTZOp6CK6S5cpebS0Mv3WbHC7f3kb@tfbwUyuXS5vlKpNCqva87RS2Rma5y8)

Comment: Demo from bobble bubble solved my problem. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to do it with a regular expression. You can use DOM to remove the links and any other HTML tags.

```js
const htmlString = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="https://example.com">example.com</a>
Pellentesque porta ligula et justo condimentum, nec tincidunt libero tempor.
Pellentesque nunc justo, tincidunt sit amet suscipit sit amet, auctor <a href="https://google.com">google.com</a>`

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");

const text = doc.body.textContent;
console.log(text);
```

If you just want to remove links and leave other HTML tags that is also possible.

```js
const htmlString = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="https://example.com">example.com</a>
Pellentesque <b>porta</b> ligula <em>et justo</em> condimentum, nec tincidunt libero tempor.
Pellentesque nunc justo, tincidunt sit amet suscipit sit amet, auctor <a href="https://google.com">google.com</a>`

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");

const anchors = doc.body.querySelectorAll("a");
anchors.forEach(node => node.replaceWith(...node.childNodes));

const htmlWithAnchorsRemoved = doc.body.innerHTML;
console.log(htmlWithAnchorsRemoved);
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern for removing all anchor tags from an text would be something like this:

```
<a.*?</a>
```

with the global tag.

It will specifically search for all the anchor tags in your string and will match it globally (i.e. all over the text which you are using). You can use this regex with replaceAll function like this:

```
let value = string.replaceAll("<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>", "");
```

You can test the regex [here](https://regexr.com/)

I have tested the given string and the output is as follows:

[image: regex-to-remove-anchor-tags-from-a-given-string]

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any queries.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Using regexp to parse html is never a good path to follow. Maybe the following will help you?

```js
const html=`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="https://example.com">example.com</a>
Pellentesque porta ligula et justo condimentum, nec tincidunt libero tempor.
Pellentesque nunc justo, tincidunt sit amet suscipit sit amet, auctor <a href="https://google.com">google.com</a>`;

function html2text(html){
 const o=document.createElement("div");
 o.innerHTML=html;
 return o.textContent;
}

console.log(html2text(html));
```

Comment: don't use `div` it will preload images and execute events. lets imagine that this is untrusted input, and the value is `<img src=x onerror=evil_script()>`. Shortly after `o.innerHTML=html` it will fetch for nonexistent `x` image and will execute `onerror` event.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for all answers. Solution from @bobble-bubble comment works for me

Code snippet below

```js
const replaceHTML = (text) => {
  const rLink = /<\/?a\b[^><]*>/gi
  
  text = text.replace(rLink, "")

  return text
}

console.log(replaceHTML(`<a href="google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a>`))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = document.createElement('template');
temp.innerHTML = text;
temp.content.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(e=>{e.replaceWith(e.href)});
console.log(temp.innerHTML);
```